# Regex first word after match and last word in specific line

Tags: regex

I am stuck with the following expression.

```
RECOVER FROM:
Company 1
Bla: Bla
Bla: Bla

DELIVER TO:
Sypris Solutions, Inc.
Street 123
City ZIP US
Bla: Bla
Bla: Bla
Bla: Bla
```

I would like to filter the company information which starts after "DELIVER TO:"

With \bDELIVER TO:\s+\K\S+, I get the first word in the first line after "DELIVER TO:" (which is fine because we only need to know the first word of the Company name to get the clue).

The goal is to have the first word in the line after "DELIVER TO:" to return as Group 1.
The last word in the third line (in this case the country code "US") should return as Group 2.

https://regex101.com/r/hU6lfr/1

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```php
\bDELIVER TO:\R\h*(\S+).*(?:\R.*){2}.*\h(\S+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hU6lfr/2)

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `DELIVER TO:` - a substring
- `\R` - a line break char sequence
- `\h*` - zero or more horizontal whitespaces
- `(\S+)` - Group 1: one or more non-whitespaces
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (the rest of  the line)
- `(?:\R.*){2}` - two lines
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\h` - a horizontal whitespace
- `(\S+)` - Group 2: one or more non-whitespaces.

Comment: I tried to integrate your solution into Zapier, but it seems it does not work there, even though it's working fine in regex101.

I used DELIVER TO:[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+) which works fine in Zapier, but gives me the whole first line instead of the first word. 

Do you happen to know why Zapier is not accepting your solution?

Comment: @Muckael Zapier uses Python `re`, and the pattern above is written for PCRE. You may try with `\bDELIVER TO:\r?\n[ \t]*(\S+).*(?:\r?\n.*){2}.*[ \t](\S+)`. The *ExtractPattern* says that the return values are *all matched groups with start and end positions*, so [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/hU6lfr/4) should work for you.

Comment: I just realized Zapier is adding an empty line between each line [like this](https://regex101.com/r/u5DNL7/1), which results in no matches. I fixed it by [adding a \n](https://regex101.com/r/u5DNL7/2).

Unfortunately, I encountered another issue: Sometimes the address is too long, resulting in [another row of address code](https://regex101.com/r/u5DNL7/3). How can I make sure it will not return the street number? It would be best to return the "City" as Group 2, skip the Zip code, and return the 2 letter country code as group 3.

Comment: @Muckael Try `\bDELIVER TO:(?:\r?\n){2}[ \t]*(\S+).*(?:\r?\n.*)*?[ \t]([A-Z]+)$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/u5DNL7/4).